# Can content loaded from amp-state JSON get indexed?

Tags: seo, amp

We're building a 100% AMP website and some of our pages load content with amp-state. Will the content get correctly indexed by Google or other search engines?

It looks like the example in [AMP's documentation](https://amp.dev/es/documentation/components/amp-list/).